# How to find which node is the currently the manager node in docker swarm in a multiple swarm manager cluster?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-swarm

I created a **docker swarm cluster** with **4 nodes** out of it **2 is swarm manager** (swarm supports multiple manager) I understand if the **current** manager node **goes down** then the **second** manager **takes the role** of being the swarm manager.

In my case I am firing the **rest call** to the swarm manager for creating the services with replicas and so on.

At some point if this manager goes down and the second manager becomes manager how do I know ??

Is there any way it gives notified that the particular node is a manager dynamically ??

Please give me the clarification on this ??

Answer (score 12):

### Using the CLI

The quick way to (manually) know if the manager changed is through the CLI:

```
$ docker node ls

ID                           HOSTNAME  STATUS  AVAILABILITY  MANAGER STATUS
46aqrk4e473hjbt745z53cr3t    node-5    Ready   Active        Reachable
61pi3d91s0w3b90ijw3deeb2q    node-4    Ready   Active        Reachable
a5b2m3oghd48m8eu391pefq5u    node-3    Ready   Active
e7p8btxeu3ioshyuj6lxiv6g0    node-2    Ready   Active
ehkv3bcimagdese79dn78otj5 *  node-1    Ready   Active        Leader
```

You can find out which Manager is the current **Leader** under the `MANAGER STATUS` column.

You can also check individually on each node formatting with the `Leader` field, for example:

```
$ docker node inspect <id-node> --format "{{ .ManagerStatus.Leader }}"

true
```

### Using the Docker Remote API

You can also check which one of the manager is the leader programmatically. The docker remote API exposes a [Nodes API endpoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.24/#/list-nodes)
 that you can use to **list nodes**.

You can provide a *filter* as a parameter which takes the `key=value` form.

You can use that filter to list manager nodes only (with `role=manager`), then you can parse and filter the JSON output to keep the node whose `Leader` field is set at `true` (under `ManagerStatus`).

Unfortunately there is no `leader` filter ([yet](https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/blob/master/manager/controlapi/node.go#L79)) but I assume that this could be a valid enhancement to propose on the swarmkit issue tracker.

There are no events stream on docker swarm mode yet (this is tracked by [this issue](https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/issues/491) on the *swarmkit* repository). I imagine that in the future, an event will trigger on Leader switch and you will be dynamically notified of the *new leader* if you are listening to these events (for example if you have a special setup and want to dynamically update entries in consul, nginx or Interlock).

Comment: That's impressive

Answer (score 12):

To find out manager nodes, run **docker info** It lists out current node address as well as manager addresses, among many other info.

The command **docker node ls** isn't very useful here as it works only from a manager node.

Comment: If running `docker info` doesn't work for you, it may be because you're running it from a node (like your local machine) that is not connected to the swarm.

To make sure you're running `docker info` from a node in the swarm, run `docker-machine ls` and make sure one of the machines has an asterisk in the ACTIVE column. If you don't see any asterisks, pick one of the machine's names from the list and run `docker-machine ssh <enter the name here> "docker info"` and that should give you the desired output from a node that is in the swarm.

Answer (score 3):

I used docker-machine to set up my local swarm (running VirtualBox).

If you run `docker-machine ls` it will already show you asterix (*) in the ACTIVE column for the leader. Alternatively use `docker node ls` to see a bit more detail - there you'll see whether other managers are reachable and which is the leader explicitly.

You will also need more than two managers for fault tolerance (check here https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/admin_guide/). Swarm managers use Raft protocol to get strong consistency. For that they need a majority of manager nodes and majority of 2 is 2, so no fault tolerance yet. Your swarm won't be able to elect new leader if the current fails.

I don't know if you can get notifications on the change of the leader. What you can do for sure is to point to any manager node so if you use REST I can imagine setting up HA proxy that would not use unhealthy nodes and point it to all your managers. Any manager can take service calls and it will forward it to the leading manager for scheduling.

Comment: I agree you have a valid point, in my case i have generated a CA certificates from swarm manager, so the manager will respond to the rest call whom ever is coming with the same CA certificates. in this case the manager cant forward the call to the another manager right ?. I struck here i am trying to figure out a way , thanks for your help that helps me a lot.

Comment: I don't see why the manager wouldn't be able to forward the call. I understood it is an internal Swarm mechanism. If I were you I would play with it and see for myself. If you find an error look for it in their bug tracking system. The current swarm mode is a bit buggy (I've encountered more then 5 already reported bugs). It's hopefully gonna be better with version 1.13.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a [distributed key/value store](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/discovery/), check its log or you could use this command on those two swarm manager, it'll show you the node which is primary.
**docker -H tcp://< swarm_ip:swarm_port > info**

With docker-machine, take a look [there](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/provision-with-machine/#/connect-node-environments-with-machine), set your shell to connect to the swarm manager and use the **docker info** command.